# EF 5.0 Enums Not Generating

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-5

**BACKGROUND**
I'm using VS 2010 on a machine where I installed .Net 4.5 which I've read was an in-place install (overrode the .net 4.0 version).

I have projects still targeting 4.0 and 4.5 option is not available but was told it's ok since 4.5 was an in-place install. I then installed EntityFramework -pre via nuget and notices when I ran Upgrade-Database -Script commands, it would not generate enum properties.

I then found [this](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/moving-projects-from-ef-4-1-2-3-ndash-gt-ef5beta-don-rsquo-t-do-what-i-did/). I tried doing everything from scratch again but it was still adding EntityFramework 4.4 instead of 5.0. So I manually changed all references to point to the 5.0 version to make sure I have EF 5.0 version. All compiled.

**PROBLEM**
When I run

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations
```

I get "*No classes deriving from DbContext found in the current project.
Edit the generated Configuration class to specify the context to enable migrations for.*"

So I manually made sure that my class is correct as in:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
```

DataContext subclasses DbContext.

When I run

```
Update-Database -Script
```

I get "*No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'MyProject'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).*"

MyProject does have the configuration class I mentioned above and in Package Manager Console I am choosign the right dropdown for my project containing Migrations folder and this Configuration class.

**QUESTION**

1. What do I do to make sure when I install EnittyFramework via nuget that it adds the 5.0 version and not 4.4 even though I have .Net 4.5 installed?
2. If I can't do anything related to the question above, what can I do to make sure Upgrade-Database spit out a script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entity Framework 5.0 isn't out yet. There are [prereleases](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0-beta2), but you need to specifically enable prereleases in order for NuGet to display them.

However, keep in mind that EF 5.0 won't support everything in .NET 4.0 that it will in .NET 4.5. Yes, .NET 4.5 overwrites .NET 4.0, but if your project is in VS2010, it will be configured to build for .NET 4.0, not .NET 4.5. It cannot assume .NET 4.5 features, because the result needs to run on systems that don't have .NET 4.5. You're targeting .NET 4.0, after all, and enum support isn't in the EntityFramework DLL you get from NuGet, it's in the System.Data.Entity DLL that's part of the .NET runtime, so it cannot be added in .NET 4.0. You can install the [Visual Studio Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us) to create applications that target .NET 4.5.

In short: "was told it's ok since 4.5 was an in-place install" -- no, it's not ok for your purposes.

Comment: Appreciate the comment. I followed Scott Hanelman's blog post about retargetting the .net framework to 4.5 using <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">. Are you saying I should upgrade to VS 11?

Comment: @gsogoly Yes, .NET 4.5 isn't supported in VS 2010. Setting `targetFramework="4.5"` in a web application means your .NET 4.0-developed application will run on .NET 4.5, but it remains a .NET 4.0-developed application, and you don't actually get any of the benefits of .NET 4.5 (except for possible bug fixes in existing methods).

Comment: Dang it, I have Win2k8 R2 32-bit version and VS11 is failing because it's not 64-bit. Is there really no other way to target .net 4.5 on VS 10?

Comment: @gsogoly VS11 should work just fine on 32-bit systems, I'm using that myself on Win7. I'm not sure about installing it on Windows Server, though. But to answer your question, there are hacks you can use to get VS2010 to accept .NET 4.5, but it involves tricking VS into thinking it's really a variant of .NET 4.0, and it doesn't play nice with NuGet (which will also see it as an unrecognised variant of .NET 4.0, and fail to install packages), so that's a no go since you use Entity Framework.

Comment: @gsogoly And a hack is the only possible way: VS2010 SP1 blacklists .NET 4.5, refusing to open any project that targets it.