# 'Enable-Migrations' fails after upgrading to .NET 4.5 and EF 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I just upgraded my MVC4 project to .NET 4.5 and EF5 and started using VS2012.
After realizing I needed to set-up auto-migrations in the Package Manager again I ran `Enable-Migrations - EnableAutomaticMigrations` and received the error

`No context type was found in the assembly 'MySolutionName'.`

Some [Research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489789/ef-5-0-enums-not-generating) has said that it has to do with EF5 not enabling prereleases. I ran `Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease` but it said EF5 was already installed (which it was when I installed it through the NuGetmanager earlier *without* specifying `-IncludePrerelease.`

Does anyone know what I have to do to enable migrations for my project?

Comment: Please ignore the misspelling of 'Prerelease' all 3 times.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just had the same problem and found your question while searching for a solution.

I got it working. The problem, for me, was that I initially targeted the .NET 4.0 framework when I added the EF 5 via NuGet. Changing the target framework and then reinstalling EF 5 via NuGet, fixed it. It's also possible (see comments) that just reinstalling EF 5 via NuGet is the solution for you.

I had the following line in the App.config file, notice Version=4.4.0.0:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

So what I did was set the target framework to 4.5 inside the solution configuration and set the supported runtime to 4.5 too (inside the app config).

Old:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
```

New:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.5" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
```

After that change, I removed EF 5.0 via NuGet and added it again. It gave me the following configSection as result,  notice Version=5.0.0.0:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
</configuration>
```

After that change, it worked.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling EntityFramework, via Nuget, then reinstalling, and the configuration files "fixed" themselves.

Comment: I also uninstalled EF via Nuget - then reinstalled and all is well

Comment: I too removed entity framework from my entire solution and reinstalled it (all via nuget) which fixed the issue.  Thanks to @mattruma

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced the same problem, but after a day I suddenly get attention to a file called packages.config in the ASP MVC 4 project folder. So, here i get

```
 <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

I changed the version number to my appropriate number i.e. for me i used EF ver 5.0.0. After I change the version, everything is fine now.