# ReflectionTypeLoadException when I try to run Enable-Migrations with Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, orm, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to use Entity Framework for the first time on one of my projects. I'm using the [code first workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542) to automatically create my database. Intitaly setting up the database worked fine. Now I'm trying to migrate changes in my classes into the database.

The tutorial I'm reading says I need to run "Enable-Migrations" in the package manager console. Yet when I do this I get the following error

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindType[TBase](String typeName, Func`2 filter, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetContextTypeRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I retrieve the loader exceptions property? Also NuGet says I have EF 5.0, but Version property of the EntityFramework item in my project references says 4.4.0.0. I'm not sure if this is related.

Comment: EF 5 only works with .NET 4.5. This is why the nuget package says 4.4.0.0. I am guessing your project is targeting the .NET 4.0 framework. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12021656/304832

Comment: @Eric: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.reflectiontypeloadexception.loaderexceptions.aspx

Comment: @danludwig 4.4.0.0 indicates EF5 for .NET Framework 4.

Comment: @Pawel, yes, that's what I was trying to say. 4.4.0.0 is EF5 for .NET 4.0.

Comment: I have this problem too... any solution?