# Enable-Migrations fails for EF5

Tags: entity-framework-5

I am using .NET 4.0 and Visual Studio 2010 (which I will eventually upgrade, but not quite yet).  I ungraded from EF 4.1 to EF 5 via NuGet and ran Enable-Migrations (via the Package Manager Console) but got this error

```
No context type was found in the assembly 'UI'.
```

I Googled around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021656/enable-migrations-fails-after-upgrading-to-net-4-5-and-ef-5) SO post.

The scenario described by the poster is slightly different as he is using VS 2012 and .NET 4.5.  Either way I'm not sure if this will solve my issues.  Do I need to be using VS 2012 and .NET 4.5 to use Migrations?  How do I solve my issue?

Comment: I know what I did wrong incidentally.  When I have a little more time I shall post up an answer.

Comment: You don't need .NET 4.5 to be able to use migrations. Probably you need to point to the assembly that contains context type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to NuGet commands work correctly, you should specify the default project:

[image]

So you should change the dropdown value from *UI* to *Model* (I presume). Actions should not depend on VS version.