# Can I get my context to inherit from an abstract class and use code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

So that I could keep my context clean and simple, I put a lot of logic in an abstract class and made my context inherit from it.

I saw this approach [here](https://github.com/kmckelvin/EFHooks) but now since my class no longer inherits directly from `DBContext` I can't create migrations.

My abstract class is

```
public abstract class MyContext : DbContext
{

    public MyContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {
    }
   public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        // custom code here
    }
}
```

Now when I try and create an migration by typing add-migration at the PM console I get an error indicating that a class inheriting from `DBContext` cannot be found

The PM console shows

```
PM> add-migration kirsten2 No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'DataLayer'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration). 
PM> Enable-Migrations No context type was found in the assembly 'DataLayer'.
```

Comment: Hi Kirsten :-)
I'll find the references to this error and tell you how to do the same when facing an issue in EF.

Comment: I think you must not declare the MyContext as an asbstract class, if then how do you want to instantiate it?
There is no way to make new object of an abstract calss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search the EF repo for this error message ("No migrations configuration type was found"), you'll find this resource in EntityFramework/Properties/Resources.cs file:

```
/// <summary>
/// A string like "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly '{0}'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)."
/// </summary>
internal static string AssemblyMigrator_NoConfiguration(object p0)
{
    return EntityRes.GetString(EntityRes.AssemblyMigrator_NoConfiguration, p0);
}
```

The next step would be search for `AssemblyMigrator_NoConfiguration` usage, and you'll find 
just one occurence which is in EntityFramework/Migrations/Design/ToolingFacade.cs:

```
private DbMigrationsConfiguration FindConfiguration()
{
    var configurationType = FindType<DbMigrationsConfiguration>(
        ConfigurationTypeName,
        types => types
                     .Where(
                         t => t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                              && !t.IsAbstract
                              && !t.IsGenericType)
                     .ToList(),
        Error.AssemblyMigrator_NoConfiguration,
        (assembly, types) => Error.AssemblyMigrator_MultipleConfigurations(assembly),
        Error.AssemblyMigrator_NoConfigurationWithName,
        Error.AssemblyMigrator_MultipleConfigurationsWithName);

    return configurationType.CreateInstance<DbMigrationsConfiguration>(
        Strings.CreateInstance_BadMigrationsConfigurationType,
        s => new MigrationsException(s));
}
```

I think now it would be easier to track the error and fix it.

I've tested it on Source code and the message was irrelevant, turns out that the rel cause is a target framework tag in app.config.

Here is the similar question with right answer:
['Enable-Migrations' fails after upgrading to .NET 4.5 and EF 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021656/enable-migrations-fails-after-upgrading-to-net-4-5-and-ef-5)

Interesting that If you run Enable-Mirations and Add-Migration pointing exactly to Context class name and Configuratin class name respectively, it works fine.
But the mentioned solution is the right solution and is easier also :-)

Comment: and finally to get the app to run we had to delete

     <startup>
     <supportedRuntime version="v4.5" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
     </startup>
From the UI app.config

Comment: The other thing we had to do was stop the mycontext class being abstract

Comment: But sadly, when adding migrations the changes to the database are not detected. The DbSet declarations seem to need to be in the class that inherits from DbContext

Comment: Ok Kirsten, If you want to manage DbSets in another file just make that Context class change to a partial calss of SyriusContext and remove Context class.